# error while executing following c# code

Tags: c#

I had try to delete a row in a table using the following code, but I got an error.

```
{System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Missing ), ], or Item in query expression 
'[CompanyID] not in (Select [CompanyID] from EmployeeDetails 
where [CompanyID] = @cmpID'.
```

Here is my code:

```
int companyID = _cmpDetailsList[i].CompanyID;        
OleDbCommand upcmd = new OleDbCommand(
    "delete * from CompanyDetails where [CompanyID] not in " + 
    "(Select [CompanyID] from EmployeeDetails where [CompanyID] = @cmpID", conn);
conn.Open(); 
upcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpID", companyID);
upcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

i modified the command to in this format

```
OleDbCommand upcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete * from CompanyDetails where [CompanyID]= @cmpID and not in (Select [CompanyID] from EmployeeDetails where [CompanyID] = @cmpID)", conn);
```

i got the following error

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[CompanyID]= @cmpID and not in (Select [CompanyID] from EmployeeDetails where [CompanyID] = @cmpID)'.

please solve it

Comment: it works for the case `Select *` for delete its the entire row so just `delete from ...`

Answer (score 10):

If you read the error, it tells you the problem:

```
OleDbCommand upcmd = new OleDbCommand(
"delete from CompanyDetails where [CompanyID] not in " + 
"(Select [CompanyID] from EmployeeDetails where [CompanyID] = @cmpID)", conn);
```

You had a `(` but no matching `)` at the end.

Comment: delete * from is valid for access...not sure what the op is using though

Comment: +1 One more thing if you could add is the usage of `@` string literal which would have made the query easier to read and spot the missing braces, the good thing is OP using parameters